# (How could one use GIS software to determine...) What latitude has equal land areas north and south?

Tags: area, measurements

There's obviously more land in the northern hemisphere than the southern, but at some point, there must be a line of latitude where the area of land above and below is exactly the same.  Is it the same latitude as the centroid of Earth's landmass?

See: [What is Centroid of all lands of Earth?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83022/what-is-centroid-of-all-lands-of-earth)

Comment: While interesting from a geography trivia standpoint, I don't see how this is a GIS question.

Comment: As per @Vince's comment, could you rephrase this as a 'how to calculate' question, showing some initial work on how you'd go about doing it?

Comment: My http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/191054/1462 doesn't answer this question, but may be helpful.

Comment: @Simbamangu is right that the real question is "how do you calculate the mean latitude of all the Earth's land surface." I assume I would take a shapefiles and do some sort of integration calculation, but i don't really know any details on GIS software.

Comment: If I used an image that uses an equal-area projection in the algorithm that @barrycarter linked to, would that give me a reasonably accurate answer?